A research about wormholes from higher dimension prespective
I want to write a research paper about higher dimension and wormholes, what could I research about? What could be the question, I have graduated from high school 1 years ago, and not recently joined college but I plan to now.

You needn’t a question to begin research. Many papers are just aggregations and analyses of existing material. It sounds like you’ve got a perfectly good research topic already (wormholes in higher dimensions).
